# Reset JDBC connections of Connection Pool in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc, high-availability

**Scenario:**

There is something called [`FAN notification`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_avail.htm#ADFNS915) in Oracle Database, which is used for `High Availability`.

Whenever I will get this notification in my Java application I want to reset all the `JDBC` connections object available in my `Connection Pool`.

But the problem is, even if I reset the connection pool objects, there will be some `JDBC` transaction going on using old connection objects.

*My question is*, can we somehow change that (which is in use)  connection object with the new object and copy or transfer the transactions to new connection object without any [`inflight transaction`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24377/trxman.htm#WLJTA361).

**[update]**: This scenario is handled between server and database using something called [Grid Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13737/gridlink_datasources.htm#JDBCA373). But I want to handle it in application end, by removing all the JDBC connection objects from connection pool, these connection objects will point to new database instance which is up and running.

If it is not possible please suggest me some alternative solution.

Comment: From the documentation it appears like what you need is already supported. There should be no need to program this behavior "Beginning with Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1), Oracle Database supports Application Continuity for Java. This feature supports the concept of commit outcome and recovery of active requests allowing JDBC-based applications in high availability (HA) infrastructures to avoid application errors from system failures by providing an immediate implicit recovery and resubmission of all active .."

Comment: @6ton thanks for the reply, yes you are correct. It is handles in database end using something called `Grid Link`. But the situation is we have handle it in **application end** by removing the JDBC connection object from connection pool. New connection objects will point to say new database instance which is up and running.

Comment: As per the documentation this support is in JDBC driver, so you shouldn't need to code for it.

Comment: @6ton please comment down the link for the documentation/ article, where you are referring to, I don't find it. Thanks.